# Flask "[Errno 113] No route to host" and I can't find out why

Tags: python, flask, wsgi

So, I've been working on a project and developed a Flask API inside of the Python framework we've developed here. For some reason, it crashes randomly after some time and, the information I get from the error message doesn't seem to tell me much about it.

This API was running perfectly for some days, until it wasn't. The code is pretty simple and provides "EventStream" data only. When it starts, I get all the messages from Flask as it's running okay. And it does. For some reason, after a short period of time (a day or less) it crashes.

The minimal code I'm using for every route is the following:

```py
    @self.__app.route('/log')
    def get_log():

      import json

      def get_data():
        while True:
          json_data = json.dumps(self.getContext().getHandler("WebLog").getHistory())
          yield "data: {}\n\n".format(json_data)
          time.sleep(1)

      return Response(get_data(), mimetype='text/event-stream')
```

I get four of these messages when it crashes:

```
Error on request:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 303, in run_wsgi
    execute(self.server.app)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 294, in execute
    write(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 275, in write
    self.wfile.write(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socket.py", line 594, in write
    return self._sock.send(b)
OSError: [Errno 113] No route to host
```

But it doesn't tell me on which line of the ApiSvc.py it gets the error. Can anybody please help me?

Comment: That sounds like a problem with your network. Can you look at logs and work out what's happening when it goes down?

Comment: This is running on a RPi on "0.0.0.0". How do I get these logs?

Comment: this can also be a firewall issue